# Max number of intent examples

Tags: watson-conversation

With Watson Conversation, is there a limit or best practice for the number of examples for a given intent? There is concern that too many examples for an intent might diminish accuracy.

Comment: http://marcnehme.com/blog/?p=402 (Found with a simple web search.) Short answer: there is no magic number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the docs at IBM Clouds, [Defining intents](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/intents.html#defining-intents) --

> **Intent limits:**
> The number of intents and examples you can create depends on your Conversation service plan

*Standard/Premium service plan*: 2,000 Intents per workspace

*Lite service plan*: 100 Intents per workspace

Both service plans above have 25,000 examples per workspace

#### EDIT

Also note: no mention of example limits is delineated within the [pricing structure](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/conversation/#pricing-block). That said, the following article is worth checking out: [Planning your intents and entities](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/intents-entities.html#planning-your-entities)